# Class not found in ProviderRepository.php error with composer install

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm currently in the process of trying to include this package in my Laravel app: https://github.com/tappleby/laravel-auth-token

I included `"tappleby/laravel-auth-token": "0.3.*"` in composer.json, like this:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "intervention/image": "dev-master",
    "laracasts/flash": "~1.0",
    "laracasts/validation": "1.1.*",
    "tappleby/laravel-auth-token": "0.3.*"
}
```

And I added `'Tappleby\AuthToken\AuthTokenServiceProvider'` and `'AuthToken'=>'Tappleby\Support\Facades\AuthToken','AuthTokenNotAuthorizedException' =>'Tappleby\AuthToken\Exceptions\NotAuthorizedException'` to `app/config/app.php`.

Afterwards I ran `composer install`. This is the way I always added packages, but now I get an error every time: `[RuntimeException]

  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Tappleby\AuthToken\AuthTokenServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/example.com/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157`

Comment: Is there a question here? I see a list of statements.

Answer (score 18):

Goto **bootstrap/cache** folder and delete config.php

Then run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: My pleasure ;-)

Comment: That fixed it for me

Comment: Please clean the cache folder. Otherwise this will not work!

Answer (score 6):

As Marcin said you shouldn't use

```
composer install
```

but

```
composer update
```

Second thing remove all the lines added to `app/config/app.php`

First run `composer update` after that put those lines in `app/config/app.php`

Then run `php artisan config:publish tappleby/laravel-auth-token` in your command line

It should publish your configuration and now you should be able to use the relevant classes

Comment: Removing the lines from app.php helped me, thanks Muhammad!

Comment: This helped me as well. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear this

Answer (score 4):

Order is mandatory, run `composer update` then add the service provider and aliases to app.php

Answer (score 4):

`php artisan optimize:clear`

`composer install`

If that don't work

1. remove composer.lock
2. remove vendor folder
3. composer install

Answer (score 1):

You should run:

```
composer update
```

and not

```
composer install
```

When adding new dependency you should always use `composer update` to update your project and not `composer install`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @KickButtowski the OP did not ask a question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your config file may be cached. Remove all files from bootstrap/cache/*

after that run

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

php artisan config:cache
```